# On demand task processing in Java EE

Tags: multithreading, jakarta-ee, batch-processing, task-queue

I am working on task processing server side application. Use case for application is:

User submit his item.
Server accept item and add to waiting queue, if task executor is busy.
User get that status of item is submitted. 
If item is on top of queue server run it as long running task and save result to database. 
User refresh application and application get result of execution from database.

It looks like model case, but I do not have experience in this type of applications.

So I search web and found JSR 352, batch processing, which use case is similar but its batch, no single item, so I do not know if it is good solution for my case. But it has nice design, and it is easy to understand.

Also I found this article http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-flexible-and-scalable which looks good.

So are there any other patterns for task processing application? Or what will be best solution?

Also it should be possible to make task executing in multiple threads.

Thanks for point me to right direction :)